# Get only one particular class using $(this).attr("class") instead of multiple classes

Tags: jquery, css, class

I need to receive the class of an element. Another plugin inserts a second class to the element but I do not want to receive this second class. So far I have:

```
target_text = $(this).attr("class");
```

Which returns at the moment:

```
some-class sfHover
```

I do not want to get the class "sfHover". How can I remove it from my variable?

(The classes I want to get are generated dynamically, so I cannot listen for specific names and only use those.)

Thanks

Comment: How do you know what classes you want to keep or remove?

Comment: @lonesomeday: I think he just wants to remove `sfHover`.

Comment: correct... Actually I just found out adding a line "$(this).removeClass("sfHover");" before setting the variable "target_text" works. I'm just not sure whether this is a good way to do it?

Comment: @maze: `sfHover` is for compatibility with IE6. If you *don't* care about IE6, then just remove the Suckerfish code entirely. If you *do* care about IE6, then check that you haven't broken it in IE6.

Comment: @maze No, it is not - you are removing the class that propably has some purpose in being assigned and you should not do that.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with the class name. Assuming that it's possible to obtain the class name, as you originally asked, what would your next action be? Maybe you can do things differently?

Answer (score 2):

```
var target_text = this.className.replace(/sfHover/, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Tomalak's answer:

Your jQuery statement returns a string (the jQuery `attr()` method returns a string), so you should manipulate it with simple javascript:

```
target_text = $(this).attr("class").replace('sfHover ','');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always know your class will be first, and you always know it will have a class:

`target_text = this.className.split(' ')[0]`

No need for jQuery methods when you are doing simple DOM stuff.

Note the above will error if the item has NO class (I think, className would be null). Might be safer to do

`target_text = this.className && this.className.split(' ')[0]`

Also, depending on what you are trying to do, you may want to consider refactoring your code to not store state in the DOM. Try to avoid storing information in the DOM, it's expensive and the DOM is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first class try: `$(this).attr("class").get(0)`

Comment: that returns a dom element and does a pointless attribute lookup did you mean to do a split on the classes and return the first item in the array e.g this.className.split(/\s+/)[0];